# Import JSON array to DynamoDB table using DB script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a JSON array (there are almost 40K items) which looks like below:

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "zip":"100001",
    "lat":"123.44",
    "long":"344.23"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "zip":"100002",
    "lat":"123.44",
    "long":"344.23"
  }
]
```

Now I need to import these JSON array data into AWS DynamoDB table using DB Script.
Please help me how we can make the script here easily and whether I can insert all 40K records at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the CLI or any of the languages DynamoDB has an SDK for. Python may be a good start. You will have to batch the records, I don’t think you can insert all 40k at once.

Comment: Agree with @RafaelAlmeida, `boto3` for Python is a good way.